# Django - Teplatetag "readmore" wants to be "readless"

Tags: python, django, templatetag

i have written a template tag some time ago which has the feature to collapse a textblock after 15 words. Now i want the exact opposite thing. i want that the user is able to get back to the original 15 words collapsed text after opening the collapsed textblock...

i know sounds a bit wired.

**readmore.py**

```
from django import template
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

import re

readmore_showscript = ''.join([
"this.parentNode.style.display='none';",
"this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('more')[0].style.display='inline';",
"return false;",

]);

@register.filter
def readmore(txt, showwords=15):
    global readmore_showscript
    words = re.split(r' ', escape(txt))

    if len(words) <= showwords:
        return txt

    # wrap the more part
    words.insert(showwords, '<span class="more" style="display:none;">')
    words.append('</span>')

    # insert the readmore part
    words.insert(showwords, '<span class="readmore">... <a href="#" onclick="')
    words.insert(showwords+1, readmore_showscript)
    words.insert(showwords+2, '">more</a>')
    words.insert(showwords+3, '</span>')

    # Wrap with <p>
    words.insert(0, '<p>')
    words.append('</p>')

    return mark_safe(' '.join(words))

readmore.is_safe = True
```

Comment: you know you can use a `template_tag` to render an html template ... thats almost certainly easier than messing with html in python ... that said does this not work? is there an error in the javascript console when you click the link to show more? ie what isnt working?

Comment: The code you see above is a template_tag ...

Comment: There are no error at all. I simply want to know how i can collapse the text back... readmore.py template tag shows more content, as the name says. I want to know how i can get back to the original shortened text made by the script from above.

Comment: ahh i understand ... well instead of setting the `display:inline` just set `display:none` ... it would probably behove you to put this in a function in javascript that "toggles" the display (ie if its shown hide it... if its hidden show it)

Comment: That's the point. No idea of JS. Hoped somebody can help me out here ...